# When should I use the new keyword in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, new-operator, keyword

I've been using C++ for a short while, and I've been wondering about the `new` keyword. Simply, should I be using it, or not?

1. With the `new` keyword...

```
    MyClass* myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass->MyField = "Hello world!";
```

2. Without the `new` keyword...

```
    MyClass myClass;
    myClass.MyField = "Hello world!";
```

From an implementation perspective, they don't seem that different (but I'm sure they are)... However, my primary language is C#, and of course the 1st method is what I'm used to.

The difficulty seems to be that method 1 is harder to use with the std C++ classes.

Which method should I use?

#### Update 1:

I recently used the `new` keyword for *heap* memory (or *free store*) for a large array which was going out of scope (i.e. being returned from a function). Where before I was using the stack, which caused half of the elements to be corrupt outside of scope, switching to heap usage ensured that the elements were intact. Yay!

#### Update 2:

A friend of mine recently told me there's a simple rule for using the `new` keyword; every time you type `new`, type `delete`.

```
    Foobar *foobar = new Foobar();
    delete foobar; // TODO: Move this to the right place.
```

This helps to prevent memory leaks, as you always have to put the delete somewhere (i.e. when you cut and paste it to either a destructor or otherwise).

Comment: The short answer is, use the short version when you can get away with it. :)

Comment: A better technique than always writing a corresponding delete - use STL containers and smart pointers like `std::vector` and `std::shared_ptr`. These wrap the calls to `new` and `delete` for you, so you are even less likely to leak memory. Ask yourself, for example: do you always remember to put a corresponding `delete` everywhere an exception could be thrown?  Putting in `delete`s by hand is harder than you might think.

Comment: @nbolton Re: UPDATE 1 - One of the beautiful things about C++ is that it allows you to store User Defined Types on the stack, whereas garbage collected langs like C# **force** you to store the data on the *heap*. **Storing data on the heap consumes more resources than storing data on the stack**, thus you should prefer the *stack* to the *heap*, except when your UDT requires a large amount of memory to store its data. (This also means that objects are passed by value by default). A better solution to your problem would be ***passing the array to the function by reference***.

Answer (score 375, accepted):

**Method 1 (using `new`)**

- Allocates memory for the object on the [**free store**](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/009.htm)  (This is frequently the same thing as the **heap**)
- Requires you to explicitly `delete` your object later.  (If you don't delete it, you could create a memory leak)
- Memory stays allocated until you `delete` it.  (i.e. you could `return` an object that you created using `new`)
- The example in the question will [leak memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) unless the pointer is `delete`d; and it **should always be deleted**, regardless of which control path is taken, or if exceptions are thrown.

**Method 2 (not using `new`)**

- Allocates memory for the object on the **stack** (where all local variables go)  There is generally less memory available for the stack; if you allocate too many objects, you risk stack overflow.
- You won't need to `delete` it later.
- Memory is no longer allocated when it goes out of scope.  (i.e. you shouldn't `return` a pointer to an object on the stack)

As far as which one to use; you choose the method that works best for you, given the above constraints.

**Some easy cases:**

- If you don't want to worry about calling `delete`, (and the potential to cause [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)) you shouldn't use `new`.
- If you'd like to return a pointer to your object from a function, you must use `new`

Comment: One nitpick -- I believe that the new operator allocates memory from "free store", while malloc allocates from "heap".  These are not guaranteed to be the same thing, although in practice they usually are.  See http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/009.htm.

Comment: I think your answer could be clearer on which to use. (99% of the time, the choice is simple. Use method 2, on a wrapper object which calls new/delete in constructor/destructor)

Comment: @jalf: Method 2 is the one that doesn't use the new :-/  In any case, there are many times that you code will be much simpler (e.g. handling error cases) using Method 2 (the one without the new)

Comment: Another nitpick... You should make it more obvious that Nick's first example leaks memory, whereas his second doesn't, even in the face of exceptions.

Comment: @Fred, Arafangion: Thanks for your insight; I've incorporated your comments into the answer.

Comment: So why we don't need to care about `new` in Java, because the garbage collector in java is auto-worked?

Answer (score 131):

There is an important difference between the two.

Everything not allocated with `new` behaves much like value types in C# (and people often say that those objects are allocated on the stack, which is probably the most common/obvious case, but not always true). More precisely, objects allocated without using `new` have *automatic storage duration*
Everything allocated with `new` is allocated on the heap, and a pointer to it is returned, exactly like reference types in C#.

Anything allocated on the stack has to have a constant size, determined at compile-time (the compiler has to set the stack pointer correctly, or if the object is a member of another class, it has to adjust the size of that other class). That's why arrays in C# are reference types. They have to be, because with reference types, we can decide at runtime how much memory to ask for. And the same applies here. Only arrays with constant size (a size that can be determined at compile-time) can be allocated with automatic storage duration (on the stack). Dynamically sized arrays have to be allocated on the heap, by calling `new`.

(And that's where any similarity to C# stops)

Now, anything allocated on the stack has "automatic" storage duration (you can actually declare a variable as `auto`, but this is the default if no other storage type is specified so the keyword isn't really used in practice, but this is where it comes from)

Automatic storage duration means exactly what it sounds like, the duration of the variable is handled automatically. By contrast, anything allocated on the heap has to be manually deleted by you.
Here's an example:

```
void foo() {
  bar b;
  bar* b2 = new bar();
}
```

This function creates three values worth considering:

On line 1, it declares a variable `b` of type `bar` on the stack (automatic duration).

On line 2, it declares a `bar` pointer `b2` on the stack (automatic duration), *and* calls new, allocating a `bar` object on the heap. (dynamic duration)

When the function returns, the following will happen:
First, `b2` goes out of scope (order of destruction is always opposite of order of construction). But `b2` is just a pointer, so nothing happens, the memory it occupies is simply freed. And importantly, the memory it *points to* (the `bar` instance on the heap) is NOT touched. Only the pointer is freed, because only the pointer had automatic duration.
Second, `b` goes out of scope, so since it has automatic duration, its destructor is called, and the memory is freed.

And the `bar`instance on the heap? It's probably still there. No one bothered to delete it, so we've leaked memory.

From this example, we can see that anything with automatic duration is *guaranteed* to have its destructor called when it goes out of scope. That's useful. But anything allocated on the heap lasts as long as we need it to, and can be dynamically sized, as in the case of arrays. That is also useful. We can use that to manage our memory allocations. What if the Foo class allocated some memory on the heap in its constructor, and deleted that memory in its destructor. Then we could get the best of both worlds, safe memory allocations that are guaranteed to be freed again, but without the limitations of forcing everything to be on the stack.

And that is pretty much exactly how most C++ code works.
Look at the standard library's `std::vector` for example. That is typically allocated on the stack, but can be dynamically sized and resized. And it does this by internally allocating memory on the heap as necessary. The user of the class never sees this, so there's no chance of leaking memory, or forgetting to clean up what you allocated.

This principle is called RAII (Resource Acquisition is Initialization), and it can be extended to any resource that must be acquired and released. (network sockets, files, database connections, synchronization locks). All of them can be acquired in the constructor, and released in the destructor, so you're guaranteed that all resources you acquire will get freed again.

As a general rule, never use new/delete directly from your high level code. Always wrap it in a class that can manage the memory for you, and which will ensure it gets freed again. (Yes, there may be exceptions to this rule. In particular, smart pointers require you to call `new` directly, and pass the pointer to its constructor, which then takes over and ensures `delete` is called correctly. But this is still a very important rule of thumb)

Comment: *"Everything not allocated with new is placed on the stack"*
Not in the systems I've worked on... usually intialized (and uninit.) global(static) data are placed in their own segments.  For example, .data, .bss, etc... linker segments.  Pedantic, I know...

Comment: Of course, you're right. I wasn't really thinking about static data. My bad, of course. :)

Comment: Why does anything allocated on the stack have to have a constant size?

Comment: It doesn't *always*, there are a few ways to circumvent it, but in the general case it does, because it's on a stack. If it's at the top of the stack, then it may be possible to resize it, but once something else is pushed on top of it, it's "walled in", surrounded by objects on either side, so it can't really be resized. Yes, saying that it always *has* to have a fixed size is a bit of a simplification,but it conveys the basic idea (and I wouldn't recommend messing about with the C functions which let you be too creative with stack allocations)

Answer (score 25):

The short answer is: if you're a beginner in C++, you should *never* be using `new` or `delete` yourself.

Instead, you should use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` (or less often, `std::shared_ptr` and `std::make_shared`).  That way, you don't have to worry nearly as much about memory leaks.  And even if you're more advanced, best practice would usually be to encapsulate the custom way you're using `new` and `delete` into a small class (such as a custom smart pointer) that is dedicated just to object lifecycle issues.

Of course, behind the scenes, these smart pointers are still performing dynamic allocation and deallocation, so code using them would still have the associated runtime overhead.  Other answers here have covered these issues, and how to make design decisions on when to use smart pointers versus just creating objects on the stack or incorporating them as direct members of an object, well enough that I won't repeat them.  But my executive summary would be: don't use smart pointers or dynamic allocation until something forces you to.

Answer (score 14):

> Which method should I use?

This is almost never determined by your typing preferences but by the context. If you need to keep the object across a few stacks or if it's too heavy for the stack you allocate it on the free store. Also, since you are allocating an object, you are also responsible for releasing the memory. Lookup the `delete` operator.

To ease the burden of using free-store management people have invented stuff like `auto_ptr` and `unique_ptr`. I strongly recommend you take a look at these. They might even be of help to your typing issues ;-)

Answer (score 11):

If you are writing in C++ you are probably writing for performance.  Using new and the free store is much slower than using the stack (especially when using threads) so only use it when you need it.

As others have said, you need new when your object needs to live outside the function or object scope, the object is really large or when you don't know the size of an array at compile time.

Also, try to avoid ever using delete.  Wrap your new into a smart pointer instead.  Let the smart pointer call delete for you.

There are some cases where a smart pointer isn't smart.  Never store std::auto_ptr<> inside a STL container.  It will delete the pointer too soon because of copy operations inside the container.  Another case is when you have a really large STL container of pointers to objects.  boost::shared_ptr<> will have a ton of speed overhead as it bumps the reference counts up and down.  The better way to go in that case is to put the STL container into another object and give that object a destructor that will call delete on every pointer in the container.

Answer (score 9):

#### [C++ Core Guidelines R.11](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-newdelete): Avoid using `new` and `delete` explicitly.

Things have changed significantly since most answers to this question were written. Specifically, C++ has evolved as a language, and the standard library is now richer. Why does this matter? Because of a combination of two factors:

- Using `new` and `delete` is potentially dangerous: Memory might leak if you don't keep a very strong discipline of `delete`'ing everything you've allocated when it's no longer used; and never `delete`ing what's not currently allocated.
- The standard library now offers [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30143936/1593077) which encapsulate the `new` and `delete` calls, so that you don't have to take care of managing  allocations on the free store/heap yourself. So do other containers, in the standard library and elsewhere.

This has evolved into one of the C++ community's "core guidelines" for writing better C++ code, as the linked document shows. Of course, there are exceptions to this rule: Somebody needs to write those encapsulating classes which do use `new` and `delete`; but that someone is rarely yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is yes - new() creates an object on the heap (with the unfortunate side effect that you have to manage its lifetime (by explicitly calling delete on it), whereas the second form creates an object in the stack in the current scope and that object will be destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

Without the `new` keyword you're storing that on [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). Storing excessively large variables on stack will lead to [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

Answer (score 2):

If your variable is used only within the context of a single function, you're better off using a stack variable, i.e., Option 2.  As others have said, you do not have to manage the lifetime of stack variables - they are constructed and destructed automatically.  Also, allocating/deallocating a variable on the heap is slow by comparison.  If your function is called often enough, you'll see a tremendous performance improvement if use stack variables versus heap variables.

That said, there are a couple of obvious instances where stack variables are insufficient.

If the stack variable has a large memory footprint, then you run the risk of overflowing the stack.  By default, [the stack size of each thread is 1 MB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686774(VS.85).aspx) on Windows.  It is unlikely that you'll create a stack variable that is 1 MB in size, but you have to keep in mind that stack utilization is cumulative.  If your function calls a function which calls another function which calls another function which..., the stack variables in all of these functions take up space on the same stack.  Recursive functions can run into this problem quickly, depending on how deep the recursion is.  If this is a problem, you can increase the size of the stack (not recommended) or allocate the variable on the heap using the new operator (recommended).

The other, more likely condition is that your variable needs to "live" beyond the scope of your function.  In this case, you'd allocate the variable on the heap so that it can be reached outside the scope of any given function.

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing myClass out of a function, or expecting it to exist outside that function?  As some others said, it is all about scope when you aren't allocating on the heap.  When you leave the function, it goes away (eventually).  One of the classic mistakes made by beginners is the attempt to create a local object of some class in a function and return it without allocating it on the heap.  I can remember debugging this kind of thing back in my earlier days doing c++.

Answer (score 0):

The second method creates the instance on the stack, along with such things as something declared `int` and the list of parameters that are passed into the function.

The first method makes room for a *pointer* on the stack, which you've set to the location in memory where a new `MyClass` has been allocated on the heap - or free store.

The first method also requires that you `delete` what you create with `new`, whereas in the second method, the class is automatically destructed and freed when it falls out of scope (the next closing brace, usually).

Answer (score -3):

The short answer is yes the "new" keyword is incredibly important as when you use it the object data is stored on the heap as opposed to the stack, which is most important!