# What is the best way to manage the lifetime of an object variable?

Tags: c++, objective-c, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use the new keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655065/when-should-i-use-the-new-keyword-in-c)

I'm not a professional programmer and I only have experience working with small projects, so I'm having a little trouble understanding what's going on here.

I usually create objects using `class_name var_name`. But now I'm 'learning' Objective-C, where almost everything is a pointer and you have more control over memory usage.

Now I'm creating an application which contains an infinite loop.

My question is, which option is a better way to manage memory usage (resulting in less memory usage)?

1. A normal declaration (for me)

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <deque>

   using namespace std;

   class myclass 
   {
     public:
       int a;
       float b;
       deque<int> array;

     myclass() {cout <<"myclass constructed\n";}
     ~myclass() {cout <<"myclass destroyed\n";}
     //Other methods
     int suma();
     int resta();
   };

   int main(int argc, char** argv)
   {
       myclass hola;

       for(1)
       {
           // Work with object hola.
           hola.a = 1;
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Using `new` and `delete`

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <deque>

   using namespace std;

   class myclass 
   {
     public:
       int a;
       float b;
       deque<int> array;

     myclass() {cout <<"myclass constructed\n";}
     ~myclass() {cout <<"myclass destroyed\n";}
     //Other methods
     int suma();
     int resta();
   };

   int main(int argc, char** argv)
   {
       myclass hola;

       for(1)
       {
               myclass *hola;
               hola = new myclass;

           // Work with object hola.
           hola->a = 1;

           delete hola;
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```

I think option 2 uses less memory and frees the deque more efficiently. Is that correct? What are the [other] differences between them?

I'm really confused about where to use each option.

Comment: Now hold on. The two versions are not doing the same thing. So, what is really the question?

Comment: Thanks for the syntax edit. I'm getting crazy to put it in the correct way.

Comment: Nitpick on your English: The word "dude" doesn't mean question, it usually means a friend. :-)

Comment: yeah, sorry. Question or doubt are the words.

Comment: ["Objective-C, where ... you have more control over memory usage"](http://files.sharenator.com/I_smell_trolls_picdump-s400x400-140822.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Use the first option. The first option creates the object instance in local storage, while the second option creates it on the free store (a.k.a the heap). Creating objects on the heap is more "expensive" than in local storage.

Always try to avoid using `new` in C++ as much as you can.

The answers to this question are a good read: **[In C++, why should `new` be used as little as possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/in-c-why-should-new-be-used-as-little-as-possible)**