# Allocate memory at runtime

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

I want to know that how can we allocate a memory block at **run-time** in C or C++ without using `malloc` and `calloc` functions.

Comment: See the related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655065/when-should-i-use-the-new-keyword-in-c

Comment: You need to get [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: You might need to walk through some tutorials.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a good place to learn a language. And it's *certainly* not a good place to learn **two** languages!

Comment: Sorry here I forgot to mention that the memory allocation has to be done without using malloc and calloc functions

Comment: ...why not? What's wrong with `malloc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, using VLA ...

```
/* fill an array, allocated dinamically without malloc,
** with 1, 2, 3, 4, ...
** then sum all of the values and print the result */
#include <stdio.h>

void vlaalloc(size_t nmemb, size_t siz, void (*fx) (void *, size_t)) {
  unsigned char data[nmemb * siz];

  fx(data, nmemb);
}

int arraysum(int *arr, size_t len) {
  int val = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) val += arr[i];
  return val;
}

void seq(void *data, size_t len) {
  int *arr = data;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) arr[i] = i + 1;
  printf("array sum is %d\n", arraysum(arr, len));
}

int main(void) {
  int n;

  if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
    vlaalloc(n, sizeof (int), seq);
  }
}
```

see [code running at ideone](https://ideone.com/QfPQJ)

Answer (score 6):

In C, use `malloc`. Don't forget to `free` after use.

In C++, use `new` and don't forget to `delete`. Or better, use `std::vector` if you want a dynamic array.

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to mention that this is to be done without malloc and calloc.

Comment: @AmitSharma: then you need to use a platform-specific API. `malloc` is the only portable dynamic allocation mechanism in standard C.

Answer (score 2):

Either [`malloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) in C, or [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) in C++.

Answer (score 2):

In C use `malloc()`

`int *a = malloc (sizeof(int) * block_size);`

In C++ use `new`

`int *a = new int[block_size];`

Note: this code uses raw pointers. C++11 has better pointers such as `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`. It is generally a good practice to prefer these smart pointers over raw pointers.

EDIT: OP needs a block so I am updating the code

Comment: In C, don't cast the return value of `malloc`. The cast is, at best, redundant; and may hide an error the compiler would have caught in its absence.

Comment: C++03 has `auto_ptr`, which is not as good as `unique_ptr` but implements automatic cleanup.

Comment: But in turn `auto_ptr` has many problems, so it's better to use the boost smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing the point of your question, as it has been adviced, you just need to use the C++ language standard constructs: new and delete/delete[].

Comment: new and delete use malloc and free behind the scenes.

Comment: No, they *might*. But they don't have to, at all.

Answer (score 0):

In C you can use:

```
malloc()
```

in C++:

```
malloc()
calloc()
```

In C++ it's better to use the new-operator.

Comment: @Xeo: The question specifically talks about *allocating memory* (not constructing objects or primitive values). So pointing out `malloc` and `calloc` for c++ is certainly not wrong (though arguably incomplete).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: We still have a `new` for that: `::operator new(std::size_t size)`. And generally in C++, you do *not* only want to allocate memory.

Comment: `calloc` is a C function, it's not C++-specific.

Comment: @Xeo: That is correct (and I agree that explicit resource management is not such a good idea) but again: using `malloc` is certainly okay for allocating a memory block at runtime as asked by the OP. In fact, it's a plausible function to use when implementing that `new` overload you mention yourself! Note that the answer *does* mention `it's better to use the new-operator`, too.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: I could swear that last sentence was edited in after my comment... anyways. What I meant was that there is (most of the time) no good reason in C++ to only allocate memory and *not* construct something in it. If you find yourself in the need for that, you either implement a library or are playing around with something you shouldn't. And if you belong to the former group, you should use `std::vector<char>` or the likes.

Comment: @Xeo Don't we have placement `new` exactly for this reason - so we can separate memory allocation and object construction?

Comment: @AzzA: Just because we have it does not mean you should use it if it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure you your question, but the simple answer is using

C:

```
malloc();
```

C++:

```
new
```

this will return a pointer to the memory and the Operating System will take care of finding it for you.

Answer (score 0):

In C, all memory allocation is done via malloc (it's in the rules), so if you want something other than malloc, it depends on what platform you're using, and you don't say.

On Linux, mmap might do what you want. No doubt windows has something else.

On some systems you might be able to grab it without asking, as long as you know where everything is, but this is mostly only for embedded systems using a basic (or no) operating system.