# The 'new' keyword and class storage

Tags: c++, class, heap-memory

In parallel with this question: [When should I use the new keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655065/when-should-i-use-the-new-keyword-in-c)

Let's say I have the following code structure:

```
class Foo{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    /* ect */
};

class Bar{
private:
    Foo A;
    /* ect */
};

int main() {
    Bar *b;
    b = new Bar();

    // call b->methods()

    delete b;
};
```

I know from the link above `b` is heap (free store) allocated. But what about the contents of `A` inside class `b`? Is it safe to assume `A` also heap allocated?

Comment: What else could it mean for `b` to be allocated on the free store but that _its contents are allocated in the free store_?

Comment: In fact `b` is not on the free store. `b` is a pointer, and it's an automatic variable in the function `main`. Once it has been assigned to in the second line of `main`, it points to memory allocated from the free store. Pedantic difference, and I expect you already know about it, but enough people come past SO who are *deeply* confused that I think it's worth keeping such things straight :-) Likewise there is no class `b`, it's class `Bar`, and the referand of `b` is an instance of that class.

Comment: @SteveJessop yes I know, I was using the terminology he was using so he could understand. But your point is well-taken. Perhaps it would be better to say `*b` is allocated on the free-store.

Comment: @Seth: oops, sorry, I intended to address the questioner, and specifically I was responding to the remark "`b` is heap (free store) allocated". You were just in the cross-fire, I didn't realize my comment can be read as a response to yours.

Comment: @SteveJessop haha no problem, text is ambiguous :) But the comment is correct even if it is read as a response to mine, so no worries.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Thanks for correcting me: "Perhaps it would be better to say *b is allocated on the free-store." Makes sense to me. Not sure if I should edit my question to reflect the right terminology; but I want other to learn from my error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"On the heap" is, pedantically, a bit of a misnomer.  C++ does not dictate the use of a heap, only that objects that are allocated using `new` are allocated on the unspecified "free-store".  Anyway...

Yes, if `B` has a member variable of type `A` and you instantiate a `B` using `new` then all of that object is on the free-store.

It's important to note however that when you do:

`B* b = new B;`

`b` *itself* is not on the free-store, but is rather an automatic variable (ie "on the stack").  The *thing that `b` points to* is on the free-store.  Automatic variables are destroyed when they go out of scope -- but the thing `b` points to in this case will not be.  If you don't `delete b;`, you'll get a memory leak.

This may be confusing and seem unimportant.  Maybe it is confusing, but it isn't unimportant.  The fact that `b` is an automatic variable that points to something on the free-store makes possible a very important idiom known as RAII, which is used for things like smart pointers.

`shared_ptr<B> b(new B);`

`b`, here, is still an automatic variable.  But when `b` goes out of scope and is destroyed, it takes the thing `b` points to with it.  Using smart pointers here will help to eliminate the memory leak created when you didn't `delete b` above.