# How and when to cast the return from malloc?

Tags: c++

I'm not sure the proper way to handle the casting of types when using `malloc`. I'm coming from Objective C where the following is perfectly legal:

```
ALuint * sources;
sources=malloc(sizeof(ALuint)*32);
```

However, in C++ the compiler says "Assigning to ALuint * from incompatible type void *".

I get that the memory returned from `malloc` is not casted as my particular type, and I get that C++ is strict with types.

Now, I could do this:

```
 sources=(ALuint*)malloc(sizeof(ALuint)*32);
```

But I have read much wiser coders than myself say never to cast in such a manner. Why not? And if not, when or how is the best time or method to make this work?

Comment: Simple answer: Don't use `malloc`.

Comment: Unless you're target pointer is `void *`, I can't think of a time you *don't* need the cast. See @chris' answer for the proper approach =P

Comment: [Here's a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used) for when to use which C++ casts.

Comment: @chris The accepted answer in that question is outstanding. Added to my bookmark list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Avoid using `malloc` in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new).
2. If you must `#1`, You [must cast the return type of `malloc` for your code to compile](http://ideone.com/VSPfXY).
3. Only exception to `#2` is if your [target pointer is a `void` pointer](http://ideone.com/C2kNhn).
4. [Not casting the return of `malloc` is (*debatebly*)considered as good practice in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc).

So, In C++ a cast is necessary. The *type* of cast to use is also important though. It should definitely not be the c-style cast. The above links were demonstration of need of cast only.

---

Now, I could do this:

```
sources=(ALuint*)malloc(sizeof(ALuint)*32);
```

But I have read much wiser coders than myself say never to cast in such a manner. Why not?

---

Because in C++ a c-style cast is defined by the standard to map to C++ cast in following order. The first one to succeed will be used:

1. const_cast
2. static_cast
3. static_cast, then const_cast
4. reinterpret_cast
5. reinterpret_cast, then const_cast

As you see a c-styled cast might in fact result in `reinterpret_cast` which is potentially dangerous as it can cast between incompatible pointer types. So if you must use `malloc` use:

```
sources=static_cast<ALuint*>malloc(sizeof(ALuint)*32);
```

Comment: Someone definitely thinks this is wrong enough for a downvote, So please enlighten the reasoning. And please do so only if the reasoning is technical.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but if you are allocating an array of `ALuint`s (or any other such types) on  the heap, for which you need a pointer, how else to do it besides `malloc`? Or should I just use `new` in this case?

Comment: You should use new in that case @SebbyJohanns.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: Neither. `std::vector<ALuint> v(n);`

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: What Lightness says. Don't use `malloc` or `new` for that matter unless you really have to.

Comment: I wish folks wouldn't always circumvent questions on here by simply pointing out that `vector` exists. It doesn't really answer the question. I have specific reasons, unrelated to this question, why I am not using `vector`.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns, If you tag it C++, but can't use parts of core C++, it at least deserves a mention. Otherwise, it's the obvious solution. `new` is generally preferred to `malloc` in C++, though.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: You have not let known of your *Specific reasons* or your inability to use `std::vector` anywhere in the Q or in the comments.`std::vector` is the best way to go about it and its a natural answer, You should be grateful to get wise answers not answers which just solve problems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655065/when-should-i-use-the-new-keyword-in-c see this for when to and not to use `new`