# Why is the new operator used in c++?

Tags: c++, new-operator

I am a Java developer who has recently gotten into c++. I've read several times that the new operator should be avoided as variables declared with it must be manually deleted. But then my question becomes: why should I ever use it?

Comment: There are rare valid use cases.

Comment: [When should I use the new keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655065/when-should-i-use-the-new-keyword-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

First, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

You can use 'placement' new which allows you to take a chunk of memory and write the object onto it. This is the only case I've ever had to use new since smart pointers became a thing.