# Is this good or bad practice with dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c++, function, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator

I've seen this used by other people and it looks really clever, but I'm not sure if it's good or bad practice. It works, and I like the way it works, personally, but is doing this actually useful in the scope of a larger program?

What they've done is dynamically allocate some data type inside the actual function argument, and delete it in the function. Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
private:
    int number;
public:
    Foo(int n) : number(n) { }
    int num() { return number; }
    Foo* new_num (int i) { number = i; }
};

void some_func (int thing, Foo* foo);

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter number: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    some_func(n, new Foo(0)); // <-- uses the 'new' operator with a function argument
    return 0;
}

// calculates difference between 'thing' and 'n'
// then puts it inside the Foo object
void some_func (int thing, Foo* foo) {
    std::cout << "Enter another number: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << "Difference equals " << foo->new_num(thing - n)->num() << std::endl;
    delete foo; // <-- the Foo object is deleted here
}
```

I knew that it was possible to use operators in function arguments, but I was only aware of doing this with the operators on levels 2, 4 through 15, and 17, as well as the assignment operators, `? :`, `++` and `--`, unary `+` and `-`, `!`, `~`, `*` and `&`, `sizeof` and casts. Stuff like this:

```
foo((x < 3)? 5 : 6, --y * 7);
bar(player->weapon().decr_durability().charge(0.1), &shield_layers);
```

So, I actually have two questions.

1. Is the `new`-as-an-argument good practice?
2. Since apparently any operator returning a type works if `new` works, are using these good practice?

   `::`, `new []`, `throw`, `sizeof...`, `typeid`, `noexcept`, `alignof`

Comment: (1) usually no - ownership is unclear. (2) too general a question.  Try and avoid `new` / `delete` in all of your programs they can almost always be replaced with `std::vector<T>` or owning smart pointers (usually `std::unique_ptr`) or just temporaries in a scoped block `{ .... }`

Comment: *I've seen this used by other people and it looks really clever,* -- Obviously you are looking at code written by Java or C# programmers trying (in a bad way) to write C++ code.  The usage of `new` to create objects is a tell-tale sign of this occurring.

Comment: Bad practice as it is very error prone and the function cannot be used if the memory was not directly allocated with `new` for no good reason.

Comment: A function argument can contain any expression.  The levels are irrelevant.  I can say `printf( "%d\n", i = 2 ** 3 );`, although I probably wouldn't.

Comment: in this case you should just pass `foo` by value as there is no gain in creating it only to be deleted immediately afterwards. check out [When should I use the new keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655065/when-should-i-use-the-new-keyword-in-c)

Comment: What is `Foo::new_num` returning?

Comment: It's a bad practice -- for one thing, a function call like `foo(new Bar, new Baz);` is almost impossible to make exception-safe (e.g. if `new Bar` is executed first, and then the `Baz` constructor throws an exception so that `foo()` never gets called, you've leaked a `Bar` object because there is no one holding a pointer to the `Bar` that can `delete` it)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's interesting, I wasn't aware, since I only know the language I'm studying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not clever at all.  It takes a function that could be simpler and more general and reduces its capabilities for no reason, while at the same time creating an entry point into your program for difficult-to-debug bugs.

It's not clear to me exactly what `Foo::new_num` is meant to do (right now it doesn't compile), so I won't address your example directly, but consider the following two code samples:

```
void bad_function(int i, F * f)
{
  f->doSomething(i);
  delete f;
}

// ...

bad_function(0, new F(1, 2, 3));
```

versus

```
void good_function(int i, F & f)
{
  f.doSomething(i);
}

// ...

good_function(0, F(1, 2, 3));
```

In both cases you allocate a new F object as part of the method call and it's destroyed once you're done using it, so you get no advantage by using `bad_function` instead of `good function`.  However there's a bunch of stuff you can do with `good_function` that's not so easy to do with `bad_function`, e.g.

```
void multi_function(const std::vector<int> & v, F & f)
{
  for(int i : v) { good_function(i, f); }
}
```

Using the `good_function` version means you're also prevented by the language itself from doing various things you don't want to do, e.g.

```
F * f;  // never initialized
bad_function(0, f); // undefined behavior, resulting in a segfault if you're lucky
```

It's also just better software engineering, because it makes it a lot easier for people to guess what your function does from its signature.  If I call a function whose purpose involves reading in a number from the console and doing arithmetic, I absolutely do not expect it to delete the arguments I pass in, and after I spent half an hour figuring out what's causing some obscure crash in some unrelated part of the code I'm going to be *furious* with whoever wrote that function.

---

By the way, assuming that `F::doSomething` doesn't alter the value of the current instance of `F` in any way, it should be declared `const`:

```
class F
{
  void doSomething(int i) const;
  // ...
};
```

and `good_function` should also take a `const` argument:

```
void good_function(int i, const F & f);
```

This lets anyone looking at the signature confidently deduce that the function won't do anything stupid like mess up the value of `f` that's passed into the function, because the compiler will prevent it.  And that in turn lets them write code more quickly, because it means there's one less thing to worry about.

In fact if I see a function with a signature like `bad_function`'s and there's not an obvious reason for it, then I'd *immediately* be worried that it's going to do something I don't want and I'd probably read the function before using it.

Comment: At the last point, it may be worth also noting that `F f; bad_function(0, &f);` is just as bad.

Comment: @dxiv: Yes, this is a decidedly non-exhaustive list of reasons why `bad_function` is bad.

Comment: What if I want to modify the object while it is being used?

Comment: @PatrickO'Brien: Then pass a non-`const` reference.