# C++ Trouble Understanding Destructor Call

Tags: c++, class, destructor

This program is designed with custom class `A` which outputs `1` when the copy constructor is called, and `0` when the destructor is called.

I copied twice, and deleted twice, yet the destructor was called 3 times, resulting in an output of `11000`. Why is this the case?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    float v;
    A() {v = 1.0;}
    A(A &a) {A::v = a.v; cout << "1";}
    ~A() { cout << "0";}
    float set(float v){
        A::v = v;
        return v;
    }
    float get(float v){
        return A::v;
    }
};

int main(){
    A a, *b = new A(a), *c = new A(*b); // output 110 (Not sure why the destructor is called in this line)
    c->get(b->get(a.set(1.0)));
    delete b; // output 0 
    delete c; // output 0
    return 0;
}
```

I tried commenting out lines of code, and through doing so have narrowed down the extra destructor call to this line:

```
A a, *b = new A(a), *c = new A(*b);
```

However, I still don't understand why the destructor is being called here.

Comment: Aside from `delete b;` and `delete c;`, `A a` is also destroyed.  What part of the output is surprising you?  You copy 2 `A`s and destroy three.

Comment: Your getter an setter functions are also not correct.  Don't use `A::v`  and your get should not have an argument only a return vallue; Move your member 'v' to a private section and call it `m_v` then your setter would be `void set(float v) { m_v = v; }` and `float get() {  return m_v;` }. Your constructor then becomes `A() : m_v{v} {}` (don't initialize members in the body of a constructor)

Comment: @Brian61354270 reminds me of why its better to drop `this->` and rather use unique names ;)

Comment: You may be interested in [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/11082165), [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/11082165), [When should I use the new keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/655065/11082165), and [C++ Core Guidelines R.11: Avoid calling new and delete explicitly](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete)

Comment: Instead of just outputing `"1"` and `"0"` in the constructor and destructor, [output the vaue of `this`](https://godbolt.org/z/b11caa8xa).  You should have quickly seen that the "mystery" destructor is called on a constructor you didn't write any output for.  That constructor is the default constructor for `A`.

Comment: If you come from a language like C# or Java, it may come as a surprise to you that `A a;` creates a proper object, not only a variable. No `new` is required. This is called an "automatic" variable. The object it names exists until the closing brace is met.

Comment: *"I tried commenting out lines of code"* -- That is a valid approach to some issues, but it's better for determining which lines *cause* something to happen, rather than determining *when* it happens. (Plus, you should have broken down your line more for more precision, as in `A a;` `A *b = new A(a);` `A *c = new A(*b);`) For timing, it is better to add output. After the line where you think the destructor is called, add `std::cout << "Variables defined.\n";`. After the "get" calls, add `std::cout << "Called get().\n";`. After each delete put a similar line. This gives you the timing.

Answer (score 5):

The destructor isn't called in that line. It is called when `A a` is destroyed. You can get a better view of what's happening when you distinguish the different objects by initializing the member with different value:

```
#include <iostream>


class A {
public:
    int v;
    A(int v) : v(v)  {}
    ~A() { std::cout << v;}
};

int main(){
    A a(1), *b = new A(2), *c = new A(3);
    delete b; 
    delete c; 
    std::cout << "bye \n";
    return 0;
}
```

[output is](https://godbolt.org/z/e5Keh16or):

```
23bye 
1
```

`delete b` prints `2`, `delete c` prints `3`, `std::cout << "bye \n"` prints `bye` and when `main` returns `a` is destroyed too which prints `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 objects of class A.
**a** - constructed with default constructor, so '1' is not printed.
**b, c** - constructed with copy constructor that prints '1'.

So you are printing '1' only for **b,c**.

The destructor is called for all **a,b,c**. For **b,c** you are calling it explicitly and for **a** D'tor is called when function (main in this case) exits.